# Need to stop Home button in android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-navigation, android-homebutton

I develop on application which contain the customize lock screen. Now my problem is there when I am on lock screen and I press home button the it take me to the my home screen because lock screen is not my home screen so I need to stop its work and my OS version is 4.2.2 so I am unable to handle the home button.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://github.com/jenuprasad/Jenu-Sample-LockScreen

Comment: Thanks jenuine for suggestion but I already develop the lock screen needed only to disable the home button so my custom home not launch while I pressed home on lock screen

Comment: disable home button or do u want launch your homescreen when home button press

Comment: Want to disable the home button on the lock screen

Answer (score 0):

For security disabling home button is forbiden.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but how the various launcher handle that things I need to customize in same manner.

Comment: Somehow it must work! See [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock)